# Change default alignment in pander (pandoc.table)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pander

I am currently switching to `pander` for most of my `knitr-markdown` formatting, because it provides such great `pandoc` support. One of the things I am not so happy with is the default center-alignment. Marketing people may love it, but for technical reports it is an horror.

The best choice used by `Hmisc` is to use left alignment for texts and dates by default, and right alignment for number of all type.

Is there a simple way to get this globally set in `pander`?

```
library(pander)
pander(data.frame(
     name          = letters[1:3],
     size          = 1:3,
     we.have.dates = Sys.Date() - 1:3
 ))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for you kind words and great question. There's a not yet well documented feature in `pander`, but you can also pass an R function as the [default table alignment](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#cell-alignment). Quick demo:

```
> panderOptions('table.alignment.default',
+     function(df) ifelse(sapply(df, is.numeric), 'right', 'left'))
> pander(data.frame(
+     name          = letters[1:3],
+     size          = 1:3,
+     we.have.dates = Sys.Date() - 1:3
+ ))

-----------------------------
name     size we.have.dates  
------ ------ ---------------
a           1 2014-11-18     

b           2 2014-11-17     

c           3 2014-11-16     
-----------------------------
```

So the trick here is to define a function which takes only one argument to be analysed, and it returns the vector of column alignment parameters.

Comment: Why isn't this default? Was pander created by "marketing people"?

Comment: By the way, I've used this on some 2-way tables I was creating. Had to substitute your `sapply` function to `apply(df, 2, is.numeric)` for it to work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio wow, I was never referred to as "marketing guy" :) About default values: these will never fit everyone's liking, but that's why I created global `panderOptions` -- which you can put to your `.Rprofile` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for making such customization a possibility. Also, thank you for taking my joke lightly, I didn't mean to be offensive. I do have the feeling such configuration would appease the majority of people using R and pander, though, so I kindly ask you to consider making it default.